# Complex Conditional Join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle11g

```
Table B
PropertyID  Property
40      (old)  Retirement 
40      (old)  Retirement 
40      (old)  Retirement 
40      (old)  Retirement 
40      (old)  Retirement 

Table A

ProplistID  ProplistCode    ProplistName    PropertyID  PropertyCode PropertyName
101 evergree    Evergreen   30  453 Retirement Center
101 evergree    Evergreen   31  454 Retirement Community
101 evergree    Evergreen   32  443 Retirement Center
101 evergree    Evergreen   33  444 Retirement Community
```

My Query

```
SELECT  t1.*, t2.PropertyCode 
FROM    Test.dbo.Table A T1 
        INNER JOIN Test.dbo.Table T2 ON T1.PropertyID = T2.ProplistID;

UNION ALL 

SELECT t1.*, t2.PropertyCode
FROM   Test.dbo.TABLE A T1
       INNER JOIN Test.dbo.TABLE B T2 ON T1.PropertyID = T2.PropertyID; 

ORDER BY 1
```

Hello I have this complex Join that I am trying to make.

I have two tables

**

- Table 1

**

```
Col A   Col B
1       3
2           11
3           1
4           11
5           3
6           3
7           11
```

**

- Table 2

**

Table 2

```
Col A   Col B   Col C   Col D
1   Hello   3   Bye
2   Hello   4   Bye
5   Hello   6   Bye
7   Hello   11  Bye
8   Hello   12  Bye
9   Hello   13  Bye
20  Hello   14  Bye
```

I Need to join them as such to get the below mentioned table

```
Col A   Col B   Col C
1   3   Hello
2   11  Hello
3   1   Bye
4   11  Bye
5   3   Hello
6   3   Bye
7   11  Hello
```

Table 1 Col A has some IDs which have a corresponding value of 3 or 11 in col B

The tables need to be joined as

If ( Table 1.Col A.Value  = 3 )

So that Table 3. Col C = Hello

Then Join on (Table 1.Col A = Table 2. Col A)

Else( Table 1.Col A.Value  = 3)

Then Join on (Table 1.Col A = Table 2. Col C)

So that Table 3. Col C = Bye

Please help me with this.

Comment: Why did you tag this with three different DBMS? Do you need to run this on all three of them?

Answer (score 0):

As far I understood, I could arrive this far. give it a try

```
select t1.cola,
t1.colb,
'Hello' as colc
from table1 t1
inner join
table2 t2
on t1.cola = t2.cola

union all

select t1.cola,
t1.colb,
'Bye' as colc
from table1 t1
inner join
table2 t2
on t1.cola = t2.colc 
order by t1.cola
```

See a demo fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/699ee/5

**EDIT:**

You are getting such result cause; you are joining on `T1.PropertyID = T2.PropertyID` and there is no matching values in `PropertyID` of both tables. So getting 0 rows. Doing a left join will definitely fetch you null's cause of no matching key.

Hope this explanation make sense to you.

**FINAL EDIT:**

I created a sample fiddle by changing you posted actual data (so that we can have match) and tested your query. It works just fine. See the fiddle here with actual data and table schema http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ab954/3.

Comment: SELECT t1.*, t2.PropertyCode 
FROM  Test.dbo.DailyBudgetExtract T1 
  INNER JOIN Test.dbo.DailyPropertylListExtract T2 ON T1.PropertyID = T2.ProplistID
  
UNION ALL 
  
SELECT t1.*, t2.PropertyCode
FROM   Test.dbo.DailyBudgetExtract T1
    INNER JOIN Test.dbo.DailyPropertylListExtract T2 ON T1.PropertyID = T2.PropertyID

Comment: @user3586244, explain more about `it wont work`. Check the posted fiddle. That's the live example and it achieves same result as you have mentioned. It absolutely works based on your post.

Comment: When I did the Left Outer join it gives NULL values for the destination coln a

Comment: When I tried with Inner Join the Query completes effecting 0 rows

Comment: @user3586244, if you have missed posting some info then can't help. based on your post my answer works perfect (see the fiddle link at end of the answer and test/verify it yourself). Moreover, don't use left join. see the answer, have used inner join.

Comment: I am doing exactly u r doing in you Fiddle. but Inner join gives no rows at all.

Comment: @user3586244, Then your provided info in post is not correct. anyway, post your actual table structure with some sample data (if possible create a fiddle). Can try then. without which I am helpless.

Comment: I have edited my actual query on the top with the actual table format. please see if this makes any sense now

Comment: @user3586244, will take a look. Give me some time.

Comment: I tried every thing certainly Have no idea for the issue

Comment: @user3586244, see edited answer. Given explanation as why you are not getting rows. no problem with my answer; issue is because of data mismatch between tables.

Comment: you are right in the set I presented is a very small subset of the data. Here there is no value but otherwise there is data out there.

Comment: @user3586244, then provide some solid data ... else how would I test at all :)

Comment: sure, Is their any way else I can show u the data with you other then this? some other safe medium

Comment: @user3586244, use the fiddle link and create a small fiddle. just few lines of proper data ... I don't need all.

Comment: @user3586244, edited my answer. Check now (mainly the demo fiddle provided). It works fine. make changes to your query accordingly (per the fiddle). Hope it helps now and Don't forget to accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #t1 (ColA int,  ColB int)
insert #t1 values
(1,  3),
(2, 11),
(3,  1),
(4, 11),
(5,  3),
(6,  3),
(7, 11)

create table #t2 (ColA int,  ColB char(5), ColC int,  ColD char(3))
insert #t2 values
(1 ,  'Hello',   3 ,  'Bye'),
(2 ,  'Hello',   4 ,  'Bye'),
(5 ,  'Hello',   6 ,  'Bye'),
(7 ,  'Hello',   11,  'Bye'),
(8 ,  'Hello',   12,  'Bye'),
(9 ,  'Hello',   13,  'Bye'),
(20,  'Hello',   14,  'Bye')


select #t1.cola, #t1.colb, #t2.colb
from #t1
inner join #t2
on #t1.cola = #t2.cola 
union all
select #t1.cola, #t1.colb, #t2.cold
from #t1
inner join #t2
on #t1.cola = #t2.colc 
order by 1
```